# Entity Framework Core renaming a database without losing inserted data

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am working on a .NetCore application that uses SQL server and Entity Framework Core. I created a database and I connect to it using the connection string that I show bellow in my json file:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;IntegtratedSecurity=true"
  }
```

The connection worked fine and I added some tables and data to it. But now I want to rename the name "MyDatabase" without losing the data that I have in my database. Is that posible?

I was thinking to rename the database in the connection string and the use the command Update DataBase, but I think that what this would do is to create another database with the new name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the database and update your connection string.

The migrations don't record the database name, as it's common to switch the database name between environments or to have multiple databases for the same EF model that you can switch among.